# fazer com que parte da minha div de zoom, é possivel?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suponhamos que eu tenha uma div de com overflox: hidden;

e coloco uma imagem de fundo em outra div, que esta dentro dela.

a imagem ocupa todo o fundo da div, porem quero que a imagem quando estiver entre 40-60% da largura da div ela seja estendida como se fosse um zoom.

Segue o exemplo que eu fiz de uma imagem
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O começo do que tentei fazer com css e html foi isso

```html
<div style="marginTop: 10px, height: 370px, overflow: hidden, backgroundColor: red, position: inherit, alignItems: center, justifyContent: center }}>
        <div id="A-negociation" style="display: 'flex', width: 'auto', left: 0, position: 'absolute', paddingLeft: 20px }}>
          
            // card do meio
           
                <div style="margin: 35px"}}>
                  <img src="http://www.imgworlds.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/18-CONTACTUS-HEADER.jpg" style="height: '300px'" alt="card aguardando" title="aguardando pagamentos" />
                </div>              
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Inclua a estrutura do HTML na pergunta bem como o CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim é possível, vc pode usar `background-size` ou `transform:scale()` para aumentar o background ou a `div` juntamente com seu background.

Com o `background-size` o tamanho da `div` sempre permanece o mesmo, 20% da largura do pai, e 110% da altura do pai, vc  só muda o tamanho do `BG` dentro do filho. Se vc quiser pode simplificar usando um *pseudo-elemento* `::after` com o `BG` etc, só fiz assim para fica mais fácil de entender ;)

**OBS:** Preferi não usar seu modelo de exemplo, pois ele está com o estilo *inline* e com a *sintax* diferente do padrão CSS normal não possibilitando a execução do *snippet* aqui

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código do modelo acima:**

```css
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url(http://www.imgworlds.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/18-CONTACTUS-HEADER.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.zoom {
    width: 20%;
    height: 110%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-image: url(http://www.imgworlds.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/18-CONTACTUS-HEADER.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: auto 150%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="zoom"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Opção com `transform:scale()`**

Repare que na verdade o elemento do meio vai ter 22% da largura do pai, pois `scale(1.2)` vai aumentar o elemento em 20%, assim como a altura vai ficar 120%, 10% pra cima 10% pra baixo. Mas o resultado ficou legal, acho que pode te atender.

```css
.container {
width: 400px;
height: 200px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
border: 1px solid red;
margin: auto;
background-image: url(http://www.imgworlds.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/18-CONTACTUS-HEADER.jpg);
background-size: cover;
margin-top: 50px;
}
.zoom {
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid #000;
background-image: url(http://www.imgworlds.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/18-CONTACTUS-HEADER.jpg);
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="zoom"></div>
</div>
```